# How can we load files under folder into Big Query from Google Storage?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a folder of files and subdirectories in the google storage. Want to upload all the files under this folder into bqdataset.bqdatatable using a schema.

If I specify a single file it successfully uploads the file but while giving a folder path it is unable to do that.

Please advise.

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It must work!
You should use below as a source

```
gs://your_bucket/your_folder/*
```

of course assuming all files have the same schema (which you should also provide)
and you load your folder into one table

it works both using BigQuery UI or programmatically with API
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs#configuration.load

Comment: Thanks Mikhail. I think there was some issue with dashboard console. The table was getting created but it was not showing up.
Thanks again for the response. It is working now.

Comment: A quick comment if someone tries to aggregate files from subdirectories. The known double star (`gs://your_bucket/your_folder/**/*.txt.gz`) doesn't work, neither the (`gs://your_bucket/your_folder/*/*.txt.gz`). There can only be one star on the text and it will include all subfolders (`gs://your_bucket/your_folder/*.txt.gz`).